# Unrar recursive in directory

Tags: extract, rar

My question is simple. Is it possible to unrar multiple rar files in diffrent directorys. Like

```
- Folder 1
--Folder 1.1
---File1.rar
--Folder 1.2
---File2.rar
```

and that the file will be extracted in the same directory were the .rar files are located. And after that the .rar and .r01 should be removed.

```
find . -type f -name '*.rar' -print0 | 
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
        dir=$(dirname "$file")
        rar=$(basename "$file")
        cd "$dir"
        unrar e "$rar" && rm "$rar"
        cd -
    done
```

I found this here but I don't know how I could add that the .r00 files get deleted too.

Sadly unrar -r extract everything to the folder where i run the command.
I hope somebody could help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use unrar, but if you use [7z](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/7z.1.html) with the -x option, files extracted from the original .RAR archive will go into their respective subdirectories.

Comment: unrar has an x parameter too, whilst I have not tested for directories, I needed this rather than unrar e for file names with output filenames  spaces in them. else is parsed it into seperate words and failed.